# Conditionally redirecting traffic with mod_rewrite dependent on protocol

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I've been writing a rewrite rule to try and redirect all of our traffic from mysite.com.au to www.mysite.com.au. I also need to conditionally redirect depending on SSL enabled or not.

I've hacked on a bit from [askapache.com](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/http-https-rewriterule-redirect.html) to create a variable that holds either *http* or *https* dependently. Below is the code I'm using:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [env=ps:https]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [env=ps:http]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com\.au(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:ps}://www.mysite.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This works fine for URLs with paths (e.g. mysite.com.au/foo redirects to www.mysite.com.au/foo) and does the *http* and *https* switch fine.

However when just accessing the domain (just mysite.com.au) it redirects to http://www.mysite.com.au/home/website/public_html/:/www.mysite.com.au/

I'm sure it's something very small and basic I'm missing - if someone could point it out, that'd be appreciated.

Thanks!

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer - it's nothing like what it seems from first glance.

I turned on *RewriteLog* and I  identified the problem. In the logs if I am using my original condition/rule and use mysite.com.au/test I see the following:

```
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:37:50 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b847d100/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/website/public_html/test -> test
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:37:50 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b847d100/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'test'
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:37:50 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b847d100/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/website/public_html/test -> test
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:37:50 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b847d100/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'test'
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:37:50 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b847d100/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/website/public_html/test -> test
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:37:50 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b847d100/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'test'
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:37:50 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b847d100/initial] (2) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] rewrite 'test' -> 'http://www.mysite.com.au/test'
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:37:50 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b847d100/initial] (2) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://www.mysite.com.au/test
```

However when I run it against just mysite.com.au I see:

```
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:38:16 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b845bc18/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/website/public_html/ ->
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:38:16 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b845bc18/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri ''
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:38:16 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b845bc18/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/website/public_html/ ->
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:38:16 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b845bc18/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri ''
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:38:16 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b845bc18/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/website/public_html/ ->
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:38:16 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b845bc18/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:38:16 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b845bc18/initial] (2) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] rewrite '' -> '://www.mysite.com.au/'
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:38:16 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b845bc18/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] add per-dir prefix: ://www.mysite.com.au/ -> /home/website/public_html/://www.mysite.com.au/
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:38:16 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b845bc18/initial] (2) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] explicitly forcing redirect with http:/.makeitmine.com.au/home/website/public_html/://www.mysite.com.au/
```

Note that the environment variable I’m trying to set (SSL on/off) isn’t being set. As such, it’s not seeing the http/https prefix and assuming it’s a relative internal path!

When I’m trying to set the environment variable, I use the following code:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [env=ps:https]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [env=ps:http]
```

The RegEx of ^(.+)$ expects a minimum of 1 character, which there is not to match! I modified it as follows:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=ps:https]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=ps:http]
```

And now it matches, even on 0 characters!

Thanks again for your help, problem solved :)

```
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:44:57 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b8478208/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/website/public_html/ ->
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:44:57 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b8478208/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:44:57 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b8478208/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/website/public_html/ ->
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:44:57 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b8478208/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:44:57 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b8478208/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/website/public_html/ ->
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:44:57 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b8478208/initial] (3) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:44:57 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b8478208/initial] (2) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] rewrite '' -> 'http://www.mysite.com.au/'
    10.1.1.1 - - [11/Feb/2013:11:44:57 +1100] [mysite.com.au/sid#b81d24f8][rid#b8478208/initial] (2) [perdir /home/website/public_html/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://www.mysite.com.au/
```